# How to allow user to close out of the web-based CrystalReportViewer parameter prompt?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, web

I have an ASP.NET site set up using the CrystalReportViewer. When the user opens a report the parameter prompt appears. If they run into a problem with the report there's no close option in the parameter prompt and the only way it seems to escape is to back out using the browser's back button.

This doesn't work for us because, for other reasons, users on this site have been instructed to not use the back button (this instruction is beyond my control.) Since the parameter prompt blocks any other links on the page users can't click to exit. How can I turn on a close button for the prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, appears this functionality does not exist in the Crystal Report Viewer for the web by design. To work around it, I wrote some Javascript for my page that injects a homemade 'Exit' button into the parameter prompt:

```
// Forces an exit button into the parameter prompt
function addExitButton() {
    // "ReportViewer" is the name of my CRV, replace with yours
    // Also, you will probably need to adjust the path to the button image URLs
    var okButton = document.getElementById('ReportViewer_submitButton');
    if (okButton != null) {
        var exitLink = '<<URL you want the Exit button to link to here>>';
        var row = okButton.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        if (row != null) {
            var spacer = document.createElement("td");
            spacer.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
            row.appendChild(spacer);
            var startCell = document.createElement("td");
            startCell.innerHTML = '<img src="../crystalreportviewers13/prompting/images/button_left_normal.gif" />';
            row.appendChild(startCell);
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            cell.setAttribute("class", "pePromptButton");
            cell.setAttribute("background", "../crystalreportviewers13/prompting/images/button_middle_normal.gif");
            cell.innerHTML = '<div class="pePromptButton"><a href="' + exitLink + '" title="Exit">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Exit&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>';
            row.appendChild(cell);
            var endCell = document.createElement("td");
            endCell.innerHTML = '<img src="../crystalreportviewers13/prompting/images/button_right_normal.gif" />';
            row.appendChild(endCell);
        }
    }
    else
        setTimeout(addExitButton, 10);
}
addExitButton();
```

This has been tested and seems to work fine.

Comment: You, sir, have saved me a whole lot of time and headache today.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone still needs a solution, here is another I wrote previously on the SAP forum that is much simpler and does not inject anything into the page. The close button actually already exists, they have simply hidden it.

http://scn.sap.com/message/14895166#14895166

> Call this function from your $(document).ready. It will automatically
>   trigger itself every 1/3rd of a second until the parameter box's Close
>   button is set to visible. After that point it will simply stop
>   running. I found this div and its class by using the 'Inspect Object'
>   feature of Chrome.
>
> Good Luck.

```
window.$my = {    
     dlgCloseBtn: $('div.dlgCloseBtn')    
};

$(document).ready(function() {    
     enableDlgCloseBtn();    
});

/*
** Loops every third of a second until the parameter box's Close button can be made visible.
*/
function enableDlgCloseBtn() {
     if ($my.dlgCloseBtn.css('visibility') === undefined) {
          $my.dlgCloseBtn = $('div.dlgCloseBtn');

     } else if ($my.dlgCloseBtn.css('visibility') !== 'visible') {
          $my.dlgCloseBtn.css('visibility', 'visible');
          return;
     }

     window.setTimeout(enableDlgCloseBtn, 333);
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's a lot less intrusive than the current answer and it also doesn't cause the page to reload.